# On a determinant inequality of positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Assume that $B$ and $A$ are two positive definite matrices. Take $B^*$ a block diagonal matrix with block $B_{11}$ and $B_{22}$ of $B$. This means the following:
$$
B=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
B_{11}& B_{12}\\
B_{21}&B_{22}
\end{array}\right],
B^*=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
B_{11}& 0\\
0 &B_{22}
\end{array}\right]
$$
It can be seen that $2B^*\succ B$ and therefore: 
$$
\det(I+2AB^*)\geq \det(I+AB).
$$
So I managed to prove that, however I have another conjecture that the following is true:
$$
2\det(I+AB^*)\geq \det(I+AB).
$$
My question is about the proof of this conjecture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick counterexample to your conjecture is

\begin{equation*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 13    & 3  & -13 &   -5\\
     3 &    4   & -3 &    4\\
   -13 &   -3   & 13 &    5\\
    -5 &    4   &  5 &   10\\
\end{pmatrix},\quad B = \begin{pmatrix} 
 15    & 3 &  -14 &   -1\\
     3 &   18  &  -6 &    3\\
   -14 &   -6  &  19 &   -1\\
    -1 &    3  &  -1 &    1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

For this choice, $2\det(I+AB^*) \approx 6\times 10^4$, while $\det(I+AB)\approx 8\times 10^4$. The $A$ above is semidefinite; if that displeases you, then just add a trivial $\epsilon I$ to it, the counterexample will still hold.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I forgot to write an important assumption about $B$. All diagonal elements are equal: $b_{11}=...=b_{nn}=K$. I am not sure if this is significant or not for the problem. As a matter of fact I was trying to find an upper bound like $C\det(I+AB^*)\geq \det(I+AB)$ for some $C$ independent of the dimension of $B$. I wonder if this is possible. My numerical evaluation of the current problem shows that with this additional assumption, we can have $C=2$. I might have mistaken somewhere. Should I post this as question, if it can be an independent problem?

Comment: Even with the all diagonal elements equal this does not hold; take the matrix $B$ that I have above, set its diagonal to 15 (it still remains posdef); the conjecture still fails. Perhaps for it to hold $C$ has to depend on $n$ (the size of the matrices)---but am not sure about that. You might want to pose it as a separate problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, a true version is $$2^n\det(I+AB^*)\geq \det(I+AB),  \quad (1)$$ where $n$ is the dimension of $A, B$.

The proof is easy, as  $2^n\det(I+AB^*)\geq\det(I+2AB^*)$. Can $2$ be replaced by a smaller constant in (1)?